# How do I extend a builder class twice using Java generics?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, nested-generics

I have a builder class that I want to extend, here is the simple version:

```
class A {
    public A withSomeAStuff() {
        return this;
    }
}
A a = new A().withSomeAStuff();
```

When I extend it, I know that I can do this without any problem:

```
class AA<T extends AA> {
    public T withSomeAStuff() {
        return (T) this;
    }
}
class BB extends AA<BB> {
    public BB withSomeBStuff() {
        return this;
    }
}
AA aa = new AA().withSomeAStuff();
BB bb = new BB().withSomeAStuff().withSomeBStuff();
```

But now I want to extend it further with another class, so I try this:

```
class AAA<T extends AAA> {
    public T withSomeAStuff() {
        return (T) this;
    }
}
class BBB<T extends BBB> extends AAA<T> {
    public T withSomeBStuff() {
        return (T) this;
    }
}
class CCC extends BBB<CCC> {
    public CCC withSomeCStuff() {
        return this;
    }
}
AAA aaa = new AAA().withSomeAStuff();
BBB bbb = new BBB().withSomeAStuff().withSomeBStuff(); //breaks here!
CCC ccc = new CCC().withSomeAStuff().withSomeBStuff().withSomeCStuff();
```

My new CCC class works fine, but my BBB class is broken and I cannot figure out why.

What do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: Note that when you compile your code (up to the second block; ignore the third for now), your compiler will warn you about "unchecked or unsafe operations". This should be your first hint that "without any problem" isn't really true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never ignore raw type warnings: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

I added a method `self()` so you only have a single unchecked cast in your code.

```
class AAA<T extends AAA<T>> {
    public T withSomeAStuff() {
        return self();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected T self() {
        return (T) this;
    }
}

class BBB<T extends BBB<T>> extends AAA<T> {
    public T withSomeBStuff() {
        return self();
    }
}

class CCC extends BBB<CCC> {
    public CCC withSomeCStuff() {
        return this;
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    AAA<?> aaa = new AAA<>().withSomeAStuff();
    BBB<?> bbb = new BBB<>().withSomeAStuff().withSomeBStuff(); 
    CCC ccc = new CCC().withSomeAStuff().withSomeBStuff().withSomeCStuff();
}
```

Comment: The key part of the answer is that BBB needs to be defined as `BBB<T extends BBB<T>>` and should be constructed as `new BBB<>()`. Then it all works, thanks!

Comment: But this is still unsafe; you are just ignoring the warning.

Comment: @newacct can you give me an example where this cast actually produces an poluted heap? (Without using another unsafe cast or raw type)

Comment: @k5_: `class Foo extends AAA<Foo>{} class Bar extends AAA<Foo>{} Foo x = new Bar().withSomeAStuff();`

Answer (score 2):

When you introduce generics in the type declaration, then use it while creating objects of the type too.

```
    AAA<AAA> aaa = new AAA<>().withSomeAStuff();
    BBB<BBB> bbb = new BBB<>().withSomeAStuff().withSomeBStuff(); //Does not break anymore.
    CCC ccc = new CCC().withSomeAStuff().withSomeBStuff().withSomeCStuff();
```

**Note:**
While this will solve your compiler error, this is not a foolproof way and guaranteed to work in every case. You will get compiler warnings to confirm that.

For example you could do,

```
BBB<CCC> bbb = new BBB<CCC>().withSomeAStuff().withSomeBStuff();
```

and get a shock during runtime.

Comment: This is only part of the issue. The definition of `class AAA<T extends AAA>` is broken, because the `extends AAA` is raw; this erases the generics on the class' methods (and its subclasses too).

Comment: @AndyTurner, True. Edited to iterate the loopholes.

Comment: Whilst that stops the initial problem, I can still easily break it with: `BBB<BBB> bbb = new BBB<>().withSomeAStuff().withSomeAStuff().withSomeBStuff(); //still breaks here`

Comment: @Codebender the problem is in the class definitions, not how they are instantiated.